# Finding Minimum 3 values from a list

Tags: java, hashmap, comparator

I am working on project where i need to find the minimum 3 three values from a **HashMap**. I have found a code that finds highest values. Here it is.

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> List<Entry<K, V>> 

    findGreatest(Map<K, V> map, int n)
    {
    Comparator<? super Entry<K, V>> comparator = 
        new Comparator<Entry<K, V>>()
    {
        public int compare(Entry<K, V> e0, Entry<K, V> e1)
        {
            V v0 = e0.getValue();
            V v1 = e1.getValue();
            return v0.compareTo(v1);
        }
    };
    PriorityQueue<Entry<K, V>> highest = 
        new PriorityQueue<Entry<K,V>>(n, comparator);
    for (java.util.Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet())
    {
        highest.offer(entry);
        while (highest.size() > n)
        {
            highest.poll();
        }
    }

    List<Entry<K, V>> result = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<K,V>>();
    while (highest.size() > 0)
    {
        result.add(highest.poll());
    }
    return result;
    }
```

How cam I modify it to find the minimum values?
Kindly help me here.
**UPDATE**:Sorry for my mistake, I was looking to find minimum values from a **HashMap**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use exactly the same code except reverse the order of the `Comparator` using [Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator c)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder%28%29).

```
PriorityQueue<Entry<K, V>> highest = 
    new PriorityQueue<Entry<K,V>>(n, Collections.reverseOrder(comparator));
```

However, that would not be the most efficient approach. It is possible to do this in one pass.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would simply sort the list via `Collections.sort( ... )` (as it seems to consist of Comparables anyway) and then return the three first (or last) elements.

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can try like this. You don't need to have a customized comparator to achieve what you are trying here.

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    list.add(23);
    list.add(65);
    list.add(85);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(54);
    list.add(5);

    Collections.sort(list);

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Collections.min(list)` to get the lowest values from list

Comment: As he's looking for the 3 lowest values, this will not help.

Comment: I agree, sorting list and then get the last three values gives you lowest 3 values from the list

Comment: @Nitesh I need 3 values not 1.

Comment: @Sheldon, try 5th answer from jude niroshan

Comment: @sheldon you may also consider looking for the minimum value in your list, remove it from the list and repeat the procedure until three elements are extracted.

Comment: That would depend on the question if finding the minimum three times (for a length of n, n-1, and n-2) plus two remove operations is quicker than sorting once. Possible, depends on the situation. Perhaps he doesn't want to modify the list, so he would need copying, too. Probably premature optimization, though.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions involving sorting the map have a runtime of O(n log(n)). The following implementation has a runtime of O(n m), where n is the size of the map and m is the size of the result, i.e. if you want the m smallest elements.

```java
public static <K, V extends Comparable<? super V>> List<Entry<K, V>> findGreatest(Map<K, V> map, int m)
{
    LinkedList<Entry<K, V>> result = new LinkedList<Entry<K, V>>();

    for (Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet())
    {
        ListIterator<Entry<K, V>> iterator = result.listIterator();
        int i = n;
        while (iterator.hasNext() && i-- > 0)
        {
            if (iterator.next().getValue().compareTo(entry.getValue()) > 0)
            {
                iterator.previous();
                iterator.add(entry);
                if (result.size() > n)
                {
                    result.removeLast();
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        if (result.size() < n)
        {
            result.add(entry);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jude Niroshan, his answer also correct one 
and you can try this also if it helps, you can change the values and check.

```
LinkedList<Integer> li=new LinkedList<Integer>();
    li.add(-8);
    li.add(0);
    li.add(10);
    li.add(-1);
    li.add(9);
Collections.sort(li);
for(Integer a:li){
        if(a<3)
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```

Comment: This simply returns all values smaller than 3 and the sorting is not needed except that the output will be sorted.

Comment: ya you can change the values and also minimum starting 3 values he want so i thought this is the good way.